# HttpURLConnection and getting ASPX page

Tags: java, android, http

So here is the problem I'm having currently...I have a ASPX script that runs on a server (let's say http://www.myserver.com/script.aspx)...when I open up this page via my web browser I get a plain text page with some data formated like this (just one line):

```
Data1|Data2|Data3|...
```

Now I need to fetch this data in my Android app which I did like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.myserver.com/script.aspx");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) urlConnection.getInputStream()));

String data = in.readLine();
System.out.println(data); // Just to print the result in LogCat for debug

urlConnection.disconnect();
```

The problem is that the resulting string only contains the letter '@'. No sign of my data. I have tried using other web page adresses (like google.com) to test if it's a problem in my code...but it works...I allways get the first line of the page (usually the first html tag, since it's a HTML web page).

I am guessing now that this is some kind of problem with the way I'm calling my ASPX script...how can I call it via Java so I get the same result as the browser (eg. the one line with my data)

Comment: why you don't output the rest of the lines, maybe that helps understanding what's going on.

Comment: also have you looked in the source of the webpage in the browser, maybe there's also extra characters, which the browser just ignores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...I needed to set the user agent to a browser. So doing

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

did the trick. The only thing I am wondering now is what user-agent would be ideal to say "I am a browser"...this seems kinda long?

Comment: There's sadly no good catch for a short user agent string... for a good read, check the [History of the browser user-agent string](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) ;)